# How to calculate p-value for Mutual Information in FNN package

Tags: r, p-value, mutual-information

I have two columns data where I want to calculate the correlation from `mutinfo()` in FNN package in R (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/FNN/versions/1.1.3.1/topics/mutinfo) and then calculate the p-value. How can I calculate the p-value after using `mutinfo()` in R?
Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `bootstrapMI` function from the `maigesPack` packages:

> This function takes a numerical matrix (or two vectors) and calculates
> bootstrapped (by permutation) p-values to test if the mutual
> information value is equal to zero. If the first argument is a matrix,
> the p-values are calculated between all pairs of rows of the matrix.

Here a reproducible example:

```r
#BiocManager::install("maigesPack")
library(maigesPack)
library(FNN)
set.seed(1) # for reproducibility 
x <- runif(50, 0, 1)
y <- rbeta(50, 1, 2)
mutinfo(x, y, k = 2)  
#> [1] 0.04406588
bootstrapMI(x, y, bRep=100, ret="p-value")
#> [1] 0.31
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: thank you, could that also work when one of x or y is binary?

Comment: @Lisa, both x and y should be numerical vectors.

Comment: I understand, but I dont get any error by using one for example as binary. But you are right. None of mutual information approaches can work when e.g outcome is numeric and exposure is binary, right?

Comment: @Lisa, Indeed! x and y need to be numeric.